# knitr kable formatting cell text as ordered list

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I'm creating a table in a rmarkdown/html document and it's inadvertently changing cell values to an ordered list when in the format of for example (123). An example is below. Any help would be most welcomed.

[image: output is here]

```
---
output: html_document
---

df <-
  data.frame(
    col1 = c("a", "b"),
    col2 = c("(123)", "(61)"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )

knitr::kable(
  df,
  format = "html",
  align = c('lr')
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are recognized as markdown and pandoc thinks that `(123)` and `(61)` are list items. Try

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "b"),
                 col2 = c("(123)", "(61)"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

df$col2 <- gsub("\\(", "&lpar;", df$col2)
df$col2 <- gsub("\\)", "&rpar;", df$col2)
```

to replace the parenthesis by their HTML [entity code](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).

**Note:** `stringsAsFactors = F` is the new default in R > 4.0

Comment: Thanks that fixes the ordered list issue but the cells are now styled as a math expression and still doesn't show the brackets, any further thoughts welcomed.

Comment: Ok, did miss that. Added another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to disable the `fancy_lists` extension.  This will apply globally to the document, so you might prefer @MartinSchmelzer's solution.

Just put this in your YAML:

```
output: 
  html_document:
    md_extensions: "-fancy_lists"
```

After you've done this, you'll only get ordered lists with numbers (no letters or Roman numerals), and they have to be in the format `1.`, not `(1)` or `1)`, etc.